# Find values for which the given expression is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, square-numbers

Find all prime numbers $p$ such that $38 p+23$ is a perfect square. $p$ can be $ 7, 11, 79$ etc. I think there would be infinitely many primes. Is there any method to determine all the solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but I doubt that this is easy.  There isn't a single polynomial (of degree $≥2$) that can be shown to take infinitely many prime values.  $x^2+1$ is still famously unsolved.  Granted, your polynomial, $\frac {x^2-23}{38}$, does not have integer coefficients but I don't see why that should make it easier.

Comment: @lulu Perhaps this problem is shown to be equivalent to that famous unsolved problem you mentioned.

Comment: Equivalent?  Surely not.  It would just be another example...but just about any polynomial you write down is an example, see the [Bunyakovsky Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture)

Comment: As a general note, it is remarkable how little is known about prime values of non-linear polynomials.  For what it's worth, I attribute that to the fact that the sum of the reciprocals of such prime values would (obviously) converge, meaning that many of the analytic methods to show that a set of primes is infinite are irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial result:**

From $$38p+19 = (x-2)(x+2)\implies x=19y\pm 2$$

we get $$2p+1= 19y^2\pm 4y \implies y=2z+1$$

so $$p =38(z^2+z)+9\pm 2(2z+1)$$

so $(A)\;\;p= 38z^2+42z+11\;\;\;\;$ or $\;\;\;\;\;(B):p=38z^2+34z+7$.

So $p$ is of that form. Now the story doesn't end...

Comment: Thank you @greedoid but 7 is a solution while 19 does not divide 15.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose :

$$38 p + 23 = (p +k)^2$$

Then we must have:

$$p^2+p(2k-38)+k^2-23=0$$

$$\Delta=-152 k +1536; k ≈ 10.1..$$

S0 $k ≤ 10$

This gives only primes 7 and 11.

Now suppose $38k+23=(p-k)^2$; then:

$$p^2-(2k+38)p+k^2-23=0$$

$$\Delta=152 k +1536  ≥ 0$$

$$k≤ -10 $$

which  for example gives $-22$ for $p=79$ .

Since the numbers below $ -10$is infinite the number of solutions can be infinite.